# How to connect my Flutter App to my Java WebApp?

Tags: java, mysql, flutter, servlets, mobile-development

I have created my website using Java Enterprise Edition (JSP/Servlets) and MySql 8 for my database. It is a typical CRUD application with a feature that let the user track the car's location.
I thought of using Flutter since it will save me time with its cross-platform capabilities but I have'nt found any documentations that will make the user login from the app to my website and fetch some data.
I'm pretty sure it is possible somehow. Otherwise is there a way to simulate my website as fast as possible without using Chrome obviously.

Comment: Use : https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/send-data to send and https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data to fetch data from your CRUD application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the concept of **Rest APis**.Simply use the **api to fetch data** and you can also save data through api.You need to **Connect** your app to your web APi.

Comment: That's helpful. Would I need to add security measurements?

Comment: yes you need to consider best practices for api security for more details read this comprehensive article https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/security/api-security